# Search using external sites Google Search

Tags: search

I am creating a Drupal site for a government agency, and we use Google Search for our websites. The problem I'm running into is the domain the site I'm creating is on is foo.com, and the search is supposed to be run through bar.gov.

My question is is there any way to get either the built in Seach module or the Google CSE module to submit the search query on the other domain? And if there isn't how would I go about creating either a block or content pane with the search box I need?

What I need is when you click Search on foo.com it directs you to bar.gov/gsearch?sitesearch=foo.com&q=terms. Specifically getting a form's action to be the bar.gov/gsearch.

Comment: @FreeRadical I know how to do that part, my issue is getting it so when you click Search on foo.com it takes you to bar.gov/gsearch?sitesearch=foo.com&q=terms

Comment: In that case, your need just to use a HTML `iframe` to embed search on the other site. That's HTML - not Drupal.

Comment: @FreeRadical I don't have any way to make changes to the other site. I made an edit so hopefully what I need is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple ,, if you know the HTML part so make your form action to the search site and call your GET parameters into the form!

something like this:

```
        <form  action="bar.gov/gsearch" target="_blank" method="GET" id="search-block-form">
        <input type="hidden" value="q" name="terms">
        <input type="hidden" value="foo.com" name="search">
<button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
    </form>
```

edit: you need to make sure you have HTML tags enabled and not stripped in anyway so the form and any other HTML tags be available .

Comment: I've tried doing that, but anytime I try putting a form in a block or content pane it just removes it.

Comment: thats weird ,, for me I had the same request in our gov sites to replace the search form with Google so I built a module which has a tpl file with the form in it .. and it works just fine? what gets removed there in your case?

Comment: It replaces everything with between <form> and </form> with <p><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

Though from your comment it sounds like I will need to create a custom module with a template for it, is that correct?

Comment: I get your problem now .. its the tags got stripped somehow .. you use CKeditor? did you use Full HTML format in your block?

Comment: I am using CKEditor and Full HTML

Comment: I didn't face such a problem maybe cuz I used custom block ,, but Full HTML should show it .. CKeditor might your problem here .. see this post https://www.drupal.org/node/2034059

Comment: Just added that to the answer so the problem will be clear to anyone :)